# Export ember project dependency licenses

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a requirement for being able to export a list of dependency open source licenses of my Ember project's non-development dependencies.

We have some Node apps and I've been able to use [license-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-checker), and that will output a a list for the Ember app as well.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be possible to separate out the dev vs. non-dev dependencies (because ember-cli installs all dependencies in `devDependencies`). This means my export contains tons of build dependencies that we never actually ship.

I've looked at [ember-cli-license](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-license) which hasn't been updated in years and [ember-cli-json-license](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-json-license) which works but has the same problem.

Comment: its not that easy. ember addons may or may not add code to your build output. There is no way to static analyze if a addon adds stuff to your production build.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to separate out the `devDependencies` from `dependencies` (non-dev dependencies).

The `--save` flag adds your dependencies to the `dependencies` object of your `package.json` file and `--save-dev` adds your dependencies to the `devDependencies`.

By default the command `ember install package-name` adds package inside your `devDependencies`.

If you want to add your package under `dependencies` object (dependencies used in production or so), you can run `npm install package-name --save`

Note: The `ember install` command is similar to the `npm install`.